# Error opening a RTF File created through Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, document, rtf

I'm trying to create an rtf file from a string. The rtf file is created successfully but when i try to open the file the following alert appears (something like):

> It was not possible to open the document "aa.rtf".

I have the following code on my project:

```
NSString* lol = @"sasasafagagsadfsada";
    NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"rtf"]];
    if ([panel runModal] == NSOKButton){
        [lol writeToURL:[panel URL] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    }
```

What's wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Who knows? What's the error code you get back? Looks like you're just ignoring it right now when it could tell you what the problem is.

Comment: i get no error on xcode. it does the work without problems. the message only appears when i try to open the file on my desktop.

Comment: Well, `NSString` will write plain text to disk, not rich text. Can you open the file if you rename it to `aa.txt`?

Comment: when i change to .txt i can open normally. but what i wanted was to create a rtf document. what can i do?

Comment: "post your answer" with the example code, on how to create a rtf file with random text, and i'll vote it! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `NSAttributedString` instead of `NSString` for rich text. Format the text however you like, then write to an RTF with:

```
NSAttributedString *str = ...;
NSData *rtfData = [str RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) documentAttributes:nil];
[rtfData writeToFile:destinationPath atomically:YES];
```

To learn how to create and manipulate an attributed string, see Apple's [Attributed String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000036i).